# Does this direct speech need a question mark?

Tags: speech, question-mark

I have this direct speech:

> "What's in the bag?"
>
> "Let me go!", said John.
>
> "What's in the bag, I said!"

Does the last line need a question mark and if so, should it be the below?

> "What's in the bag? I said!"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comma and question mark usage for a question plus (pseudo-) quotative all in direct speech](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/617611/comma-use-for-a-question-in-direct-speech)

Comment: This is simpler than the linked question.  Because it's exactly repeating direct speech, it's just quotation within quotation: "'What's in the bag?' I said!"